# Setting my screen resolution only affects desktop size

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an LCD with native resolution 1920x1080. It works fine (tested with other computers). I have a computer with an MSI FX5200 (MS-8911) display adapter (i.e. nVIDIA GeForce FX 5200 NV34). When I use Nvidia's control panel to set a single display, I can't go above 1280x1024 screen resolution. That is, the options are there, but when I choose a higher resolution, the actual display resolution does not change, but the desktop size increases, i.e. I need to scroll up-down or sideways to get to the edge of the desktop.

What can I do to actually set my resolution to 1920x1080? Is this even possible, or am I hitting a limitation of my display adapter?

PS - Using Windows XP; the cable is DVI.

Comment: In 95% of these cases simply pressing the **Auto Adjust** button on the monitor resolves this - the video card is obviously generating the proper resolution...

Comment: @M.Bennett: My 'Auto Adjust' is disabled when working in this display mode (it isn't disabled usually.)

Comment: What do you mean by display mode? I think you should try leaving the nvidia control panel settings to default stuff, better yet disabled/uninstalled.

Comment: I mean, if I change the resolution to 1920x1080, the monitor's 'Auto Adjust' is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your monitor are set to plug and play.

Try to adjust the monitor driver to LCD 1920x1080, i remember that there should be one provide under microsoft, something like LCD "1920x1080" or "generic monitor (1920x1080)".

you got the problems because the window believe that your monitor is only 1280x1024.
while you are going to virtual desktop mode when u set higher for resolution with display card.

Comment: I can't find something like "generic monitor (1920x1080)" in the driver list. The closest I have is "Digital Flat Panel 1600x1200".

Comment: try this link, http://download.cnet.com/Digital-Flat-Panel-1920x1080-60Hz/3000-2108_4-97547.html   you probably didn't turn on window update

Comment: Tried the link; it sends me to MS Update, and there are no relevant updates for me to download there.

Answer (score -1):

Check to make sure that you are using the actual monitor driver for your monitor, rather than a generic Windows VGA monitor.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use that monitor anyway, so I can't check... thanks though.